# How to define usort for my array to be sorted in a specific order?

Tags: php, class, similarity

I am trying to build a php class which should sort my results coming from a mysql database in the order of their "similarity" to the entered search query. I am using the php function similar_text.

```
class compare { 

static $_base = NULL; 

static function setBase($base) { 
    if (!isset ($base) or !is_string($base)) { 
        $base = "";
    } 
    self::$_base = strtolower($base); 
} 

static function cmp($a) { 
    if (!is_string(self::$_base)){ 
        self::setBase(); 
    } 
    similar_text(self::$_base, strtolower($a), $a_pct); 
    return $a_pct;  
}

static function eachcmp($src, $arr)
{
    $ordered = array();
    foreach($arr as $key => $val)
    {
        $sim = cmp($val);
        $ordered[]["something"] = $arr[$key]["something"];
        $ordered[]["something2"] = $arr[$key]["something2"];
        $ordered[]["sim"] = $sim;
    }
}
```

}

As you can see in the function "eachcmp" I am comparing each value in the array with the Base and then writing all the values into a new array. Now my problem starts here. How can I now order the array in the order of $ordered[]["sim"]? I know I probably need to use usort, but I dont know which function to give as parameters for usort.

Thx for help!
phpheini

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think your function should look like this:

```
static function eachcmp($src, $arr)
{
    $ordered = array();
    foreach($arr as $key => $val)
    {
        $sim = cmp($val);
        $data = array();
        $data["something"] = $arr[$key]["something"];
        $data["something2"] = $arr[$key]["something2"];
        $data["sim"] = $sim;
        $ordered[] = $data;
    }
}
```

Otherwise you would be creating the new array elements in the `$ordered` array.

Now for the `usort`. `usort` expects an array and a comparison function. In PHP >= 5.3 you can use lambda functions for that. A suitable comparison function for your need might look like this:

```
 usort($ordered, function($a, $b) {
    $al = intval($a["sim"]);
    $bl = intval($a["sim"]);
    if ($al == $bl) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($al > $bl) ? +1 : -1;
 });
```

Comment: Ok, thank you! I created a new function comp now.
`function comp($a, $b) {
 $al = intval($a["sim"]);
 $bl = intval($a["sim"]);
 if ($al == $bl) {
  return 0;
 }
 else return ($al > $bl) ? +1 : -1;
}`
I am calling that function inside the function eachcmp. So I added `usort($ordered, comp($src, $sim));` to eachcmp. But it gives me an error: usort() [function.usort]: Invalid comparison function

Comment: You need to give a callback function, what you are giving is a function result. Try `usort($ordered, "comp")`.

Comment: But this way I am not giving the functions the $a and $b values.

Comment: You don't need to, usort is doing that internally. That why it's called a callback. usort expects a callback function that takes to arguments.

Comment: Ok, Im trying to make it work but there are like 1000 different errors :(

Comment: usort() [function.usort]: Invalid comparison function